# Use same class to parse XML messages with namespace and without namespace

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

I need to parse XML messages using the JAXB but received xml messages are inconsistent in namespace between different clients.

I found that namespaces are defined either in @XMLElement annonated class itself or in package-info.java but how can I define two different namespaces for same java class?

Comment: Why do you try to bend the XML parsing site and not tell the clients to correct the obvious incorrect XML files? Namespaces are a fundamental part of XML, and if they does not use them correctly, they produce invalid XML. Period.

Comment: I agree, but clients enforce to have the same structure for XML except for the namespace.

Comment: Then tell them that this is not the way to go. An XML with no or another namespace is a complete other XML!

Answer (score 0):

I've found that it's best to put the variant documents through an XSLT transformation so they're all in a common format before you do any further processing. That's especially so if the variation is essentially a trivial namespace difference.

Of course @Seelenvirtuose is quite correct that there's a root-cause problem here which ought to be addressed; if the namespaces aren't under control, then the data quality probably isn't under control either.

Answer (score 0):

Namespace Filters are helpful in this scenario.